# Java compiler error, cannot resolve R, build failed

Tags: android, build-error, javacompiler, aapt2

I'm newbie here, I have some problem in my script

Hope you guys help me

In this picture, My R script cannot resolve, and My Build failed, and Java Compiler error

[image]

This build failed logs

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

and this Java Compiler error logs

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

**FYI**

> I have done all the ways to solve this problem from various sources such as threads on this web, google, and youtube
>   but all did not work
>   I really hope that some of you will be kind enough to help me solve this problem

Thank You

Comment: The R class is "red" because there was an issue with your resources and therefore it hasn't been generated (it gets generated after resource linking is successful). Once you fix your resources, the R class will be generated again. To find the errors ("check the build log"!) go to the Terminal window and run "gradlew assemble" and update the question with the output. I'll help you solve the errors.

Comment: I've tried your solution but 2 errors come out

`1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' property 'incrementalFolder' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\yoga\AndroidStudioProjects\Thalia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml'.`

Comment: `2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details`

Comment: does the file C:\Users\yoga\AndroidStudioProjects\Thalia\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml exist? Can you run "gradlew clean assembleDebug"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. Go to *Gradle Scripts* --> *build.gradle (Project: X)*

And look for the line

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

I had to replace this line with

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

After changing that line I just synced Gradle, which gave me an error and a prompt to download the files. 
After that it worked like a charm.

Comment: This my classpath
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`
and I try your solution but still not working
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build option at the top of android studio hit on Rebuild project or clean your project.

After that i hope i will work well.